# Android ndk runtime - cannot locate symbol OPENSSL_init_ssl

Tags: android, android-ndk, cross-compiling

I crosscompiled openssl 1.1.1g and i crosscompiled libcurl including the openssl.
Crosscompilation went trough without a problem, no linker errors on libcurl nothing.

Then i included these two openssl and libcurl into my application where again no linking errors. But runtime shows this:

```
D/dalvikvm( 4018): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.app-1/libnative-lib-logger.so 0x419cbc60
E/dalvikvm( 4018): dlopen("/data/app-lib/com.app-1/libnative-lib-logger.so") failed: dlopen failed: could not load library "libcurl.so" needed by "libnative-lib-logger.so"; caused by cannot locate symbol "OPENSSL_init_ssl" referenced by "libcurl.so"...
```

---

Update:

The library libnative-lib-logger.so is loaded via System.loadlibrary

CMakeFiles compiles the native-lib-logger and links with libraries libcrypto, libssl,libcurl, libz,...

This all worked in openssl 1.0.2 but using the 1.1.1g i come to this error.

Reverted to older libs (openssl, curl):

```
D/dalvikvm( 4526): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.app-1/libnative-lib-logger.so 0x419c1010
D/dalvikvm( 4526): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.app-1/libnative-lib-logger.so 0x419c1010
```

Building of openssl: https://pastebin.com/tnNfvw7z
Building of libcurl: https://pastebin.com/wQ5md83f

Sorry for the pastebin but scripts are not small.

I have no idea what to look for anymore :S
All the help would be verrrry appriciated!

Comment: You haven't shown us how you're building the libraries, or how you're loading them in your app.

Comment: System.loadlibrary(libnative-lib-logger); si the java part, but libcurl and libcrypto,libssl are ndk linked with libnative-lib-logger with target_link_libraries (... libcrypto, libssl, libcurl). The process works as i have working solution with openssl 1.0.2 but new crosscompiled openssl with which libcurl and logger is built has this error. Again the compilation has 0 errors :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mixing openssl versions is unlikely to work. on your case you are loading  libcurl built against openssl 1.1.1 headers but old libssl is either already loaded or it is beign loaded at runtime.
Remember, it is flat symbol namespace, having two libraries with the same symbol names is at best going to crash or at worst do something incredible nasty, on this case, with your crypto, which is a highly undesirable outcome.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, your view goes in the direction that old libcrypto or libssl is still being loaded somewhere else. I am 99.9% sure that i rebuilded everything while having in the folder structure only new openssl, so i dont know where it could come from. Anyway to find that out ? apart from ldd where android libs don't have apparent versions

Comment: other library searchinv paths appear in ld.so.conf,  LD_LIBRARY_PATH or whatever other implementation-defined search paths, that should be described on your operating system docs.

Comment: you were probably correct. I have build openssl with variant name 111g, resulting in libcrypto111g.so and libssl111.g and recompiled all libs like libcurl to use the new libs, verified with NEEDED and it works. So probably it was really pickingup some old openssl libs from system